# Ajax using jQuery for alert not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### Problem

My application is not alerting

### Javascript - /assests/js/global.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view").click(function(){
        var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();

        //alert(customer_id);
        $.post('/index.php/ajax/customer_comission',
        {'customer_id' : customer_id },
        //Server responds to request
        function(result){
            alert(result);
        });
    });
});
```

### View

```
<p>
    <label for="customer_list">Customer Name</label>

    <?php echo form_dropdown('customer_id',$cust,'','id = "customer_id"'); ?>
</p>
<?php
    $btn_data = array(
        'name' => 'View',
        'id' => 'view',
        'content' => 'View Commission'
    );
?>

<?php echo form_button($btn_data); ?>
```

### Controller - ajax.php

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
    }
    function customer_comission()
    {
        echo 'AJAX response !';
    }
}
```

Comment: instead `/index.php/ajax/customer_comission' try with '/ajax/customer_comission`

Comment: @SureshKamrushi same result !

Comment: check in browser console, if there is any error message.

Comment: I think there is some error for not including view

Comment: CSRF Protection enabled in your config? If not then do you have a form open somewhere thats not seen on the example?

Comment: @ArunKillu did not get you. I am able to alert the `customer_id`, problem is with my ajax part I think

Comment: @SureshKamrushi changing `/index.php/ajax/customer_comission` to `ajax/customer_comission` finally worked !

Comment: I'll share this http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x so you can work through and understand all the parts & how to debug, instead of someone just giving you the answer for rep points :-)